# What's the technique behind animation on a web page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web-applications

Although we can achieve fantastic animations through various Javascript libraries such as jQuery. I am wondering what's the technique behind the animation?

I can think of using CSS to format the page element.

But how can we place an element on arbitrary position of the page? I mean, not by lines. Is it true that we can think of the client area within the browser window as the Paint canvas?

I am totally new to frontend Web development, I hope I made myself clear. And thank you for answering this junior question.

Comment: There is no technique? All jQuery does is increment or decrement CSS values over a certain time interval to make elements move on the screen, looking like an animation, and that's all there really is to it, no magic required!

Comment: - But how can we place an element on arbitrary position of the page? Using CSS positioning and setting the element's top and left values. Please see http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp As pointed out by adeneo, all jQuery does is changing these CSS properties to achieve the desired animation.

Comment: Here's a live example http://jsfiddle.net/zYKEw/ using what @MrUpsidown said

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jQuery way - and the only cross-browser way - to animate is to set some CSS properties, wait a little, update those properties, wait a little, update those properties...

```
e.style.position = "absolute";
time_start = Date.now();
time_end = time_start + 10000;

(function tick(){
  now = Date.now() - time_start;
  if(now > time_end) now = time_end;
  e.style.top = now * speed + top_start;
  if(now < time_end) setTimeout(tick, 13);
}();
```

The CSS properties you are interested in are:

- `position: absolute` lets you position the element to an arbitrary location.
- `display: block` or `display: inline-block` lets an element to have a `width` and `height`
- `top`, `left`, `bottom`, `right` define the element position if its `position` is `absolute` or `relative`. `left` takes precedence over `right` and `top` takes precedence over `bottom`.
- `width` and `height` define the element's size.
- `opacity` can be animated to fade an element in or out.
- `padding`, `border-width`, `margin` and their respective components can all be animated.

You can also animate colors: `border-color`, `color`, `background`.

Comment: Thanks to all of you. Although I am not quite familiar with CSS details right now, YOU guys have un-veiled the core concept behind all the magic and gave me a very impressive start. It will greatly help me with my further study. Thanks!

Comment: It seems my next step should be get familiar with CSS.